# Strange actions with item selection on a ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Could someone please help before this drives me completely insane!

Imagine you have a list view.  It has in it 9 items, but there is only space to display 6 without scrolling.  If an item is selected the background colour will change to indicate this.

If you select any item from 2 to 8 inclusive all is well in the world.

If you select item 1 it also selects item 9 and vica versa.  Also with this selection if you scroll up and down a random number of times, the selection will change.  If you continue to scroll up and down, the selection changes back to 1 and 9.  The value of the selected item is always the actual item you selected.

This is my code from my adapter :

```js
public class AvailableJobAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JobDto> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<JobDto> items;
    private LayoutInflater vi;

    public AvailableJobAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<JobDto> items) {
        super(context, 0, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        JobDto jh = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.inflator_job_list, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.numberText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
            holder.descriptionText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
            holder.statusText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.numberText.setText(jh.getJobNumber());
        holder.descriptionText.setText(jh.getDescription());
        holder.statusText.setText(jh.getStatus());

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView numberText;
        public TextView descriptionText;
        public TextView statusText;
    }
}
```

and this is the code from my click listener :

```js
jobs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Button btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);

                view.setSelected(true);

                int selected = position;

                int pos = val.get(selected);

                int firstItem = jobs.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                int viewIndex = selected - firstItem;

                if (pos == 0) {


                    jobs.getChildAt(viewIndex).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.selected));

                    val.set(selected, 1);

                    selectedCount ++;

                } else {

                    jobs.getChildAt(viewIndex).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.unselected));

                    val.set(selected, 0);

                    selectedCount --;
                }

                if (selectedCount > 0 ){
                    btnOk.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    btnOk.setEnabled(false);
                }

            }

        });
```

I have spent hours researching this and trying various suggestions.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

****EDIT****
After playing with some suggestion I tested it with a HUGE list. This is exactly what the behaviour is :-

If your screen has space for 10 items,  if you select item 1 it also highlights 11, 21, 31, 41 etc.

Anything in between these values behaves correctly.

Comment: What is `val`? I don't see the declaration

Comment: val is an ArrayList of Integers that im using to take care of remembering multiple selections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this guide](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView):

> When your ListView is connected to an adapter, the adapter will instantiate rows until the ListView has been fully populated with enough items to fill the full height of the list. At that point, no additional row items are created in memory.
>
> Instead, as the user scroll through the list, items that leave the screen are kept in memory for later use and then every new row that enters the screen reuses an older row kept around in memory. In this way, even for a list of 1000 items, only ~7 item view rows are ever instantiated or held in memory.

That's the root of the problem you are facing. You are changing the background color of the views in your click listener. But once a selected item is scrolled out of the screen, its view will be reused for the new item that is swiping in. As the reused view had its background color changed, the new item will consequently have that same color.

You need to take in account that views are recycled, so they might be "dirty" when you get them in `getView()`. I recommend you to take a look at the guide from where I got the quotes above, it's a nice and important read.

One possible way to fix that is to add a boolean field to your JobDto class and use it to track if an item is selected or not. Then in `getView()`, you could update the background color accordingly. You'll also probably need to add the item root view(convertView) to your ViewHolder in order to change its background color.

Comment: apologies for the delay - got pulled off onto something else.  This has nailed it for me.  Thanks for your help (and everyone else)

Answer (score 0):

In setOnItemClickListener() just update setSelected() true of false for clicked position and notifydataset. In getView put a condition

```
if(jh.isSelelcted())
{
// background is selected color
}else{
// background is non selected color
}
```

note : handle else condition.